# How can I tell if my bathroom ceiling vent is working properly?

Tags: hvac, vent, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

Seems to take the vent forever to clear shower vapor from room. I purchased a vent that had a good rating. It is vented to the outside. How do I know if it is working properly and actually venting to the outside?

Comment: Is it a passive vent, or does it have a fan?

Comment: Need more details.  Is there a fan?  Can you hear it spinning?

Comment: Rip one square of toilet paper, and hold it up to the intake while the fan is on.  If the paper sticks to the vent, it's working. Remember, a ventilation fan has to be [sized properly for the room](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/21576/33).

Comment: How big is your bathroom and what vent/fan is installed?

Comment: I can tell if my upstairs vent is on by looking at the grill cover's slats on outside of the house: they'll be sticking out. Also, when I bought my last bathroom ceiling fan I checked online and learned about the cubic feet per minute required per square foot of bathroom space, and bought a fan that could move that much air.

Comment: The vent to the outside could also be an issue. Is it clogged? Does the vent on the outside open correctly? Is the size of the pipe big enough? Length, duct type (flex vs rigid) and number of elbows also effect the efficiency of the fan, eg, each [adjustable elbow adds the equivalent of 15' to the pipe length](http://inspectapedia.com/BestPractices/Table6-13.jpg).